# How do these new-fangled phone chargers achieve step-down?

Tags: transformer, adapter

There appear to be two kinds of power supply adapters in market.

The first/older kinds were such that they were reasonably heavy and had a small transformer inside the adapter itself. The newer ones in market (those that come with a mobile phone for instance) are surprisingly lightweight; I find myself wondering whether there is even a transformer inside.

How do these new-fangled adapters achieve step-down?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

These are called *switched-mode* or *switching* power supplies.

Yes, they still have a transformer inside. That's necessary, otherwise the low-voltage side wouldn't be touch-safe.
The transformer is kept very small. That's possible because it works at a very high frequency; the mains voltage is rectified and a high-frequency switcher feeds the transformer. The higher the frequency the better the energy transfer between primary and secondary are. Remember that transformers only work on *variations* in current/magnetic field, so a higher frequency makes for more changes.

Power supplies like this are not only recognizable by their light weight, they usually accept a wide range of input voltages as well, like 100V to 240V.

**edit**
This is [a clever method](http://power-supply-directory-circuit.blogspot.com/2009/11/miniature-isolated-acdc-power-supply.html) which allows using a small transformer:

[image]

Here the high frequency comes from two spikes per 50/60Hz period, where a capacitor discharges into the transformer when a small thyristor switches the voltage near its maximum. Due to the brief transfers (once per 10/8.33ms) this is only suitable for low power applications. The schematic shows a 150mW supply.

Comment: Lost me there; do you mean the mains voltage is rectified first, and then stepped down? Could you point me at a link please?

Comment: Yes, rectified first and then stepped down. If I can find a link I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: actually rectified first, converted to high-frequency AC, stepped down, and then *rectified again*.

Comment: Uh. Here on the sub-continent supply lines are typically 240V. Wouldn't a 1KW diode (assuming 240V 5A point) be pretty large to fit into the charger plug?

Comment: @Everyone - Yes, it would, but you don't have a 5A diode because you can't draw 1kW from the adapter. You may have up to 20W (e.g. 4A @ 5V), but that will translate to less than 100mA @ 240V.

Comment: @tcrosley, why do they do it that way instead of rectify and then DC-DC (buck converter)?

Comment: @Matt B. You need isolation for safety. Bucking the rectified AC is fine to make a rail that's not touch-safe (i.e. an internal housekeeping supply for a microwave or washing machine) but if the end user can touch it, it has to meet safety requirements (including isolation).

Comment: @Everyone: There's an application note that shows in great detail how one could implement these types of switched power supplies: http://www.powerint.com/sites/default/files/PDFFiles/der265.pdf (Disclaimer: I do not work for Power Integrations, I just happened to stumble across it). It's consistent with tcrosley's comment: the high voltage end is rectified, converted to HF AC, then rectified and filtered.

Comment: @Insilico: Sweet! Great link! +1